# C# sometimes freezing form when running a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, freeze

I mentioned in an other question, that I'm working on an ffmpeg-parser with progressbar and so on.

The following problem is not 100% reproduceable. When I convert a video file with my program the most time anything is ok. It work perfectly on smaller files (~100MB out), but on lager files (~1GB out) sometimes the gui freezes, but ffmpeg is working on (the debugger still gets the output from ffmpeg and displays it, so the form-thread doens't freeze, only the gui of the console)

I also realized that ffmpeg does the job it has to do without any errors that may raises the freeze.

The form also freezes if I run it outside the Debug-Environment.

The parsing works on an extra thread to handle the output of ffmpeg async.

I think this thread freezes, and the main program will hang up after ffmpeg has finished, because the parser getting a `command == null` with wich the main program will be messaged that the convertion is done. I actually can't say this, because atm I can't reproduce the freeze and the last time I forgot to mention if the debugger outputs `"======== #"` or not.

You can find the source (with ffmpeg in debug-folder) [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sc2translate/files/dev_ffmpeg_parser/) as ConvertApp.zip

talking between processes:

```
    // message directors for threading
    private BlockingCollection<string> commandsForParser = new BlockingCollection<string>();
    private BlockingCollection<string> commandsForMain = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    // sending commands to threads
    public void SendCommmandParser(string command)
    {
        commandsForParser.Add(command);
        //Debug.WriteLine("P: " + command);
    }
    public void SendCommmandMain(string command)
    {
        commandsForMain.Add(command);
        //Debug.WriteLine("M: " + command);
    }
```

the call for parsing:

```
    private void showParsedConsole()
    {
        ConsoleOutput dlg = new ConsoleOutput();
        dlg.Show();

        //...

        while (true)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

            string command = commandsForParser.Take();
            
            // if null, ffmpeg finished
            if (command == null || command == "..break..")
                    {
                        SendCommmandMain("..break..");
                        dlg.Close();
                        break;
                    }

            if (dlg.toClose)
            {
                SendCommmandMain("..cancel..");
                dlg.Close();
                break;
            }
            else if (command != null)
            {
                //... actualizing form (output, progress things)
            }
            else
                dlg.addMessage("\n");
        }
    }
```

starting the convertion:

```
    public string RunExternalExe(string info, string filename, string arguments = null)
    {
        // parse console in new thread
        var thread = new Thread(showParsedConsole);
        thread.Start();

        //...

        #region init process to run
            var process = new Process();

            process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arguments))
            {
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            }

            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            var stdOutput = new StringBuilder();
            var errOutput = new StringBuilder();
        #endregion

        #region redirect stdOut/stdError
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
            {
                SendCommmandParser(args.Data);
                stdOutput.Append(args.Data + "\n");
                Debug.WriteLine("S: " + args.Data);
            };
                            
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
            {
                SendCommmandParser(args.Data);
                errOutput.Append(args.Data + "\n");
                // if the form is freezing, the debugger will still output these
                Debug.WriteLine("E: " + args.Data);
            };
        #endregion

        #region run process
            try
            {
                process.Start();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                while (!process.HasExited)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

                    string command = commandsForMain.Take();

                    if (command == "..cancel..")
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("============== 1");
                        process.Kill();

                        while (process != null && !process.HasExited)
                        {
                            //wait
                        }
                        // return if canceled to provide excetion (process == null)
                        return "C";
                    }

                    if (command == "..break..")
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("============== 2");
                        process.WaitForExit();
                        break;
                    }
                    /*...*/
                }

                Debug.WriteLine("============== 3");
                SendCommmandParser("..break..");
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        #endregion
            Debug.WriteLine("============== 4");
    

       //... handling OK, CANCEL, ERROR
    }
```

Can anybody find a structural problem, which will raise this freeze?
(actually I run 2 convertions without any error, but not had changed the code)

Thanks for your help.

~ADD~
now I got a freeze-run, and the debugger doesn't outputs `"============== #"`, so the parsing thread did really freeze... but why?

Comment: If you're calling `Application.DoEvents()` *and* using a thread, you *must* be doing something wrong. You absolutely shouldn't need to call `Application.DoEvents()` unless there's a problem with the design. All the work should be done in the thread. The UI should always be responsive then. And you mustn't call `Application.DoEvents()` - did I mention that? ;)

Comment: and how shall I reorganize this? If I outcomment `Application.DoEvents()` in `showParsedConsole()` the ParsingForm freezes. And the worker should call the ParsingForm not the other way round, because the form is only a display for the work of it. The problem is, that the worker have to wait until ffmpeg is ready, and I have actually no idea how to reorganize...

Comment: It looks to me like your entire `RunExternalExe()` should be run from a separate thread. It might be easiest for you to use a [BackgroundWorker component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to run it in a separate thread.

Comment: I thought about a little bit and anytime I see the problem, that the main program (gui) have to wait for the converting process to be finished. Not at all cost in this small program, but in the program I developing it for. And I actually see no way to hold the gui unfreezed without using `Application.DoEvents()`.
In the program I develop it for, the main gui has to wait with proceeding until all convertions have been done. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Matthew, it really seems that the `Application.DoEvents()` raised the freeze. 
I don't know why, but I completely reorganized the code, so the main gui sends the convertion requests to a `BlockingCollection<>`, which will be worked off by a new thread.

To hold the window unfreezed, I initialized it with the main-gui-thread and updated it from the working thread with `Invoke`s.

It was hard work to reorganize the other project, because the main form was calling different convertions with conditions on their succeeding, but actually it works.

And for the future I know: just call intensive work with only one call of an class, to make a later parallelization easier ;)